# Re-nest arrays into tree using its field as parameter

Tags: php, arrays, nested

I'm losing my hair on this one... I have an array structure that `print_r`'s like this (I've hidden unnecessary fields):

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 14
        [name] => Foo Directory
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 16
        [name] => Bar Project
        [parent] => Array
            (
                [id] => 14
                [name] => Foo Directory
            )
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 20
        [name] => Baz Project
        [parent] => Array
            (
                [id] => 16
                [name] => Bar Project
            )
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 10
        [name] => Qux Project
        [parent] => Array
            (
                [id] => 16
                [name] => Bar Project
            )
```

And I need it to be nested like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 14
        [name] => Foo Directory
        [children] => Array
            (
                [id] => 16
                [name] => Bar Project
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 20
                        [name] => Baz Project
                    )
                    (
                        [id] => 10
                        [name] => Qux Project
                    )
            )
    )
```

What I've tried so far

```
$projTree = array();

    foreach ($projects as $project) {
        if (isset($project['parent'])) 
            array_push($projTree['children'], $project);
        $projTree['id'] = $project['parent']['id'];
    }
```

But that overwrites the previous inserted element. I also tried to walk it recursively, but couldn't figure out the correct callback for that, since it only operates on the leafs of the tree and I need to fully walk it.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Let me solve that for you.

Comment: Damn, looks like someone got the solution for oyu.

Comment: I'm developing some big projects @HassanAlthaf, there'll be more issues to solve! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try like below:-

```
<?php
$array = Array(
    '0' => Array
    (
        'id' => 14,
        'name' => 'Foo Directory'
    ),
'1' => Array
    (
        'id' => 16,
        'name' => 'Bar Project',
        'parent' => Array
            (
                'id' => 14,
                'name' => 'Foo Directory'
            )
    ),
'2' => Array
    (
        'id' => 20,
        'name' => 'Baz Project',
        'parent' => Array
            (
                'id' => 16,
                'name' => 'Bar Project'
            )
    ),
'3' => Array
    (
        'id' => 10,
        'name' => 'Qux Project',
        'parent' => Array
            (
                'id' => 16,
                'name' => 'Bar Project'
            ) 
    )

);
$new_array = array();
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
foreach ($array as $key=>$val){
    if(array_key_exists('parent',$val)){
        foreach($new_array as $key1=>$val1){
            if($val['parent']['name'] === $val1['name']){
                $new_array[$key1]['children'][$i]['id'] = $val['id'];
                $new_array[$key1]['children'][$i]['name'] = $val['name'];
            }else{
                foreach ($val1['children'] as $key3=>$val3){
                    if($val['parent']['name'] === $val3['name']){
                        $new_array[$key1]['children'][$key3]['children'][$j]['id'] = $val['id'];
                        $new_array[$key1]['children'][$key3]['children'][$j]['name'] = $val['name'];
                    }
                    $j++;
                }
                $i++;
            }   
        }   
    }else{
        $new_array[$key] = $val;
    }
}
echo "<pre/>";print_r($new_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/419591

Comment: Well, that's nice! Just killed some fields from children projects but that was expected since I've omitted some of them, so I'll just adapt it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AedixRhinedale But make sure you simply this code into different methods/functions.